# How to tag an image in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, tags, dockerfile, docker-image

I have been digging the documentation, but I did not find an instruction to define the tag name of an image in a `Dockerfile`. There is one available for the command line though.

Say I create an image `FROM` another image, I don't want it to bear the same name. How should I proceed?

Comment: Can't the cmd ```docker build -t shykes/myapp:1.0.2 -t shykes/myapp:latest .``` resolve you issue?

Comment: It leaves a taste of incompletion: half of the abstraction lies within Dockerfile, and the rest on the command line. ^^ So why not just using the `FROM` on the command line, and the `RUN` too while at it, thus get rid of the Dockerfile.

Comment: I use a Makefile for this.  The 'build' target lets me just run 'make build' and it executes the 'docker build -t ....' stuff.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. You can use `build.sh` script, which contains like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    tag='latest'
  else
    tag=$1
fi

docker build -t project:$tag .
```

Run `./build.sh` for creating image `project:latest` or run `./build.sh your_tag` to specify image tag.

Comment: The Zsh script can be quite compact: `docker build -t project:${1:-'latest'} .`